# Programmatically log out a user

Tags: grails, spring-security

Upon user login I check their roles. If they have no roles I want to log them out. This is what I am doing now:

```
if (SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
    redirect(uri: '/book/edit')
}
else if (SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
    redirect(uri: '/book/list')
}
else {
    redirect(uri: '/login/auth')
}
```

This doesn't work because there is a recursive redirect to `/login/auth`. How do I do this properly (logout and then redirect to `/login/auth`)?

Comment: Why not make this users, w/o roles, as a disabled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class AnyController {    
    def logoutHandlers

    def method = {
    ...
        logoutHandlers.each { handler ->
            handler.logout(request, response, springSecurityService.authentication)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what would i pass in as `request` and `response`? is there some kind of an http function that will give me these?

Comment: no. They are standard HttpRequest and HttpResponse objects accessable for every controller

Answer (score 9):

Btw, to logout currently logged in user, you can make following call:

```
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()
```

Comment: Extremely useful in integration tests